# Content-Encoding header on html files within specific folder in AWS S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, http-headers

I have just created a custom error page, but for some reason I cannot set several headers on the file(s).

Currently my headers look like this:

```
X-Firefox-Spdy  h2
accept-ranges bytes
age 432
content-length 1931
content-type text/html
date Fri, 06 Oct 2017 10:55:47 GMT
etag "6fc24050256bab8cec351de1c6c74a4f"
last-modified Fri, 06 Oct 2017 10:55:33 GMT
server AmazonS3
via 1.1 a57f85bbf89c6dasdasdasddcddasd9687e0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id JZAiF7gZnnUVrorerfasusQu84gQVGwV0UU4h3mjaw4E-CKL2_Xm6zOg==
x-cache Error from cloudfront
```

but should really look like this:

```
X-Firefox-Spdy h2
age 1512
content-encoding gzip
content-type text/html
date Fri, 14 Jul 2017 06:42:03 GMT
last-modified Sat, 17 Jan 2015 17:35:49 GMT
server AmazonS3
vary Accept-Encoding
via 1.1 a57f85bbf89c6dasdasdasddcddasd9687e0.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id JZAiF7gZnnUVrorerfasusQu84gQVGwV0UU4h3mjaw4E-CKL2_Xm6zOg==
x-cache Error from cloudfront
```

There is an option in metadata to enter Content-Encoding, but when I enter gzip, I keep getting an error and page is not being displayed. In addition to this, header Accept-Encoding cannot be set and when I am trying to delete accept-ranges header, it keeps coming back again and again.

What should I do or what should not do to make it right.

Comment: what is the error message do you get?

Comment: Content Encoding Error

Comment: I have done it partly, I have had to use 7zip to gzip the original file then upload it to my S3 bucket, then added Content-Encoding gzip and it worked. Now I need to get rid of accept-ranges bytes header and content-length header and add vary Accept Encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the documentation on how to setup S3 or custom origins to serve compressed data transfer through cloudfront,

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/ServingCompressedFiles.html

One does not need to compress file and store it in S3. Cloudfront will automatically handle that for you.

Hope it helps.